# TableForm with a title

Tags: formatting, grid-layouts

My question is rather simple. 
I want to put a title into a table.

For example, consider a list with depth two and a title

```
list = Range[4] & /@ Range[4];
title = "Bravo";
```

And I want to create a table from `list`, i.e.,

```
TableForm[list]
```

This will generate a table without a title. 
Let's say I want to make a title "Bravo" on top of the table(which is center-aligned).

Can you suggest a neat way to achieve it? I looked up the possible options for `TableForm`, but I could not find a relevant one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Labeled[TableForm[list], title, Top]
```

[image]

```
Panel[TableForm[list], title, Top, Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image]

Note: To remove quotes in `title` you can use:

```
Labeled[TableForm[list], Style[title, ShowStringCharacters -> False], Top]
```

[image]

**Update:** Post-processing the output of Jen's method to center the label and remove the divider line:

```
ClearAll[labelF]
labelF = RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#] /. HoldPattern[RowLines -> _] :> Rule[RowLines, False] ] &;

labelF@TableForm[{{list}}, TableAlignments -> Center, TableHeadings -> {None, {title}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is another approach using only the functionality of `TableForm` itself:

```
list = Range[4] & /@ Range[4];
title = "Bravo";
TableForm[{{list}}, TableHeadings -> {None, {title}}]
```

[image: table]

This nests the `list` deep enough inside `{{  }}` so that the column labels provided by `TableHeadings` are applied only to a single column containing the actual table. The result is that the column heading has become a table heading for the inner table.

Answer (score 1):

```
Column[
{ToString["This is the title"],
TableForm[yourdata]},
Alignment-> Center]
```